# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll

Tags: c#, azure, service

Additional information: The request has timed out after 00:00:00 milliseconds. The successful completion of the request cannot be determined. Additional queries should be made to determine whether or not the operation has succeeded.

I'm following the tutorial at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee706736.aspx and I'm getting the above exception after running the console program and putting in my access information. I put the policy name and the access key and the namespace in the login details but it doesn't seem to work.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Description;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceBus.Samples
{
[ServiceContract(Name = "IEchoContract", Namespace = "http://samples.microsoft.com/ServiceModel/Relay/")]

public interface IEchoContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    String Echo(string text);
}

public interface IEchoChannel : IEchoContract, IClientChannel { };

[ServiceBehavior(Name = "EchoService", Namespace = "http://samples.microsoft.com/ServiceModel/Relay/")]

class EchoService : IEchoContract
{
    public string Echo(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Echoing: {0}", text);
        return text;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;



        Console.Write("Your Service Namespace: ");
        string serviceNamespace = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Your Issuer Name: ");
        string issuerName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Your Issuer Secret: ");
        string issuerSecret = Console.ReadLine();

       // Create the credentials object for the endpoint.
        TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerSecret);


        // Create the service URI based on the service namespace.
        Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "EchoService");

        // Create the service host reading the configuration.
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EchoService), address);

        // Create the ServiceRegistrySettings behavior for the endpoint.
        IEndpointBehavior serviceRegistrySettings = new ServiceRegistrySettings(DiscoveryType.Public);

        // Add the Service Bus credentials to all endpoints specified in configuration.
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(serviceRegistrySettings);
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);
        }

        // Open the service.
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service address: " + address);
        Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Close the service.
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

}